# Spark 2.0 pre - CSV parsing error if missing values in date column

Tags: r, date, csv, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

Trying to read a CSV file to Spark (using SparkR) containing just this data row:

```
1|1998-01-01||
```

Using Spark 1.6.2 (Hadoop 2.6) gives me

```
> head(sdf)
  id          d dtwo
1  1 1998-01-01   NA
```

Spark 2.0 preview (Hadoop 2.7, Rev. 14308) fails with error:

> Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
>     org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:289)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:98)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:124)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:124)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Itera...

The problem seems indeed the NULL value here as with a valid date in the third CSV column it works.

R code:

```
#Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = 'c:/spark/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6') 
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = 'C:/spark/spark-2.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)

sc <-
    sparkR.init(
        master = "local",
        sparkPackages = "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0"
    )
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)


st <- structType(structField("id", "integer"), structField("d", "date"), structField("dtwo", "date"))

sdf <- read.df(
    sqlContext,
    path = "d:/date_test.csv",
    source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
    schema = st,
    inferSchema = "false",
    delimiter = "|",
    dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    nullValue = "",
    mode = "PERMISSIVE"
)

head(sdf)

sparkR.stop()
```

Any idea what the problem is? Should a bug report be opened? (I am rather inexperienced with Spark, so I consider it likely that I am just doing something wrong...)

Comment: As there is no reaction yet it may indeed be a bug... Thus I opened a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16460 after finding https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark, but no existing issue in the project's JIRA.

Comment: Yes it seems that it is a bug. SOers who end up here, please vote for the issue.

Comment: Yes, and in the meantime its been fixed... :-) see the link above.

Comment: Not quite! The ticket is still open and the pull request is still pending, but it looks promising.

Comment: Well, I pulled the pending pull request, compiled it and ... here we go. If the pull request is still open the bug must also be present in the final Spark 2.0 release.